# Process does not kill on form close

Tags: c#, winforms

I have just built version one of my testing application using Windows Forms. I have noticed that when running the application, it runs completely fine no hitches, exactly like the debug view. When it comes to closing the application I have noticed that the actual executable/process name hangs within Task manager and does not correctly close.

Upon further inspection I have noticed that when calling another form without hiding the previous form, a new process is spawned (kinda expected). When closing the new form (containing a few text boxes, labels and a `DataGridView`) the newly spawned process does not kill it's self, but remains.  Then closing the main window the window disappears from the taskbar/view, but still, the processes remain active using 8,268k - 8,308k Memory

[image: Task Manager]

```
    private void ClientSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientSearch Clientsearch = new ClientSearch();
        Clientsearch.Show();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: are you using Threads? Do they have IsBackground set to true? Do you save configuratio to file or do any work in OnFormClose?

Comment: Can you post come code where you are calling `form.Show()`?

Comment: @AndrewGrinder Please see my update. Added the code where I am showing the form which spawns a new process

Comment: @DarylGill so when you start the app, it creates multiple processes? or does it create multiple process after you click "Client Search"?

Comment: @AndrewGrinder Essentially, when I click Client Search. Just by primary observations, before getting to this screen there is a login form which is hidden after authenticated credentials, no new process is spawned. Once getting to the loggedin form/window/screen, a new process will be fired up when the button is pressed

Comment: Ya that is weird. So what I usually do is have my main form (host the navigation) hidden and show the login form. Reshow the main form if credentials are correct on the login form. Did you check for any threading like @firda asked?

Comment: How do you create the process? Creating new Form does not create new process, the forms share message loop (one process, one main thread pumping messages). Are you sure that all Forms are CLOSED and not only HIDDEN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard explanations for this behavior:

- Hiding your main window when you display another window and forgetting to unhide it.  There is no visible window anymore, nor can the user do anything to unhide it, but your app keeps motoring of course.
- Starting a thread and not making sure that it is terminated when the main window closes.  Setting the thread's IsBackground property to *true* is a workaround for that.
- Calling Application.DoEvents() in your code.  A very dangerous method that permits you to close the user interface but doesn't stop the loop in which it was called so the main thread of your app does not exit either.

This kind of problem is readily visible as well when you debug your app.  You might have gotten in the habit of using the red rectangle on the toolbar (aka Debug + Stop Debugging) to force the debugger to quit.  The Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window can provide insight into the cause of the last two bullets.  Or you can use Tools + Attach to Process to attach the debugger to a zombie process.

Answer (score 5):

Call

```
Application.Exit();
```

on form close/closing.

Your applications should only be creating one process per run. A new form should not be creating a new process.

Comment: Hmm, any ideas where I may have messed up, as you say the application should be creating more than one process. So I've done something wrong somewhere along the way